# Is expm1 the right primitive?

Tags: floating-point, integration, special-functions

I'm writing some code to calculate $\int_0^1 e^{ax} \mathrm{d} x$. Annoyingly there does not seem to be a way of doing this without `if` statements:

```py
def my_integral(a):
    if a == 0:
        return 1.
    else:
        return expm1(a)/a
```

(I know comparing to zero looks worrying, but this correctly returns `1` for values like `1e-50`)

It got me thinking; `expm1` is really standard, but why isn't the right primitive `expm1_over(x) = expm1(x)/x`?

`expm1_over` can do everything that `expm1` can, and more.

Am I missing some drawbacks?

Comment: What's wrong with this question?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with computational sciences. It's more about the implementation of a certain library, which of course is off-topic here.

Comment: I removed the reference to a specific library. Arguably `exmp1` is a cross-library phenomenon. Numpy, MATLAB, cmath all have it as a primitive. My question is that from a theoretical perspective, wouldn't it make sense to have something else? Is this a historical accident? Or are there drawbacks to "expm1_over"?

Comment: Simply removing reference to specific library doesn't make your question on-topic. Besides being off-topic because you are trying to argue about whatever function, your question is off-topic for another reason also because it's not clear what you are asking literally.

Comment: Numerical stability is a pretty important component of computational science. That said, I'm also unclear what the question is.

Comment: The question is, if you developed a new language for numerical computation, would you include `expm1` or `expm1_over`? Example answers include "yes, `expm1` is more numerically stable, it's used for a reason" or "expm1_over is better but it's too late to change" or "`expm1` is much faster" etc etc

Comment: In my opinion, there is nothing wrong with the question (I edited the tags though), it is certainly on-topic here, even with or without mentioning of numpy (which has no real importance to the question).

Comment: @AloneProgrammer the list of on-topic is [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This particular question would correspond to multiple points: programming that requires computational science experience, is of numerical nature and is high-level wrt numpy or an abstract numerical library implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is very well arguable that $\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ is ``as right as'' `expm1`. It appears frequently in applications; see for instance Sections 2.1 and 10.7.4 of Higham's Function of Matrices, which mention exponential integrators and matrix functions; this function is called $\psi_1(x)$ there. Your example, integrating exponentials, is another one, and it is very relevant in probability applications as well. Personally, I have encountered $\psi_1$ more often than `expm1` in my research.

As @WolfangBangerth notes in his answer, it is not really a big deal in practice, because one can be computed from the other with high relative accuracy. It seems to me that the only annoyance is the one you point out.

Answer (score 2):

`expm1` is a primitive because for small $x$, the Taylor series for $e^x=1+x+x^2+\cdots$ adds small terms to one -- which implies that if $x$ is small enough, you lose almost all digits of accuracy other than the leading one and so the expression $e^x-1$ can not be accurately computed by first evaluating the exponential.

The fact that you happen to have an application that requires some other primitive has no impact on the usefulness of `expm1`. I will, however, point out that there is no reason to invent your `expm1_over` primitive because the operation `(e^x-1)/x` can be accurately computed using first the `expm1` primitive followed by the division, without loss of accuracy.